# Сохранение текста кнопки в JSON

Tags: java, android

Есть несколько однотипных кнопок `Button` в приложении, изначально они прописывались обычным способом:

```
Button exec1Set1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exec1Set1);
exec1Set1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Внутри обработчика события `onClickListener` текст с данных кнопок сохраняется в виде `JSON` для последующего сохранения в БД:

```
JSONObject ex1 = new JSONObject();

try {
    ex1.put("set1",exec1Set1.getText().toString());
    ex1.put("set2",exec1Set2.getText().toString());
}
```

Для оптимизации решил создавать кнопки динамически как в одном из примеров на SO - [пример на GitHub](https://gist.github.com/zapl/2f94844ef4aef9df6a8206f06c474597). Теперь никак не пойму как мне для этих кнопок также упаковывать текст в `JSON`. Пробовал делать через цикл:

```
int i = (int) v.getTag();
while( i < 3 ){ 
    ex1.put( "set" + i,((Button) v).getText().toString() );                    
    i++;
}
```

но он получается не срабатывает вообще - значения в `JSON` ( в данном случае с предполагаемыми именами "set0", "set1" и "set2") не добавляются.

**UPD:**

Кнопки создаются следующим образом:

```
private List<Button> buttons;
private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS = {
        R.id.exec1Set1,
        R.id.exec1Set2,
        R.id.exec1Set3,
        R.id.exec2Set1,
        R.id.exec2Set2,
        R.id.exec2Set3,
        R.id.exec3Set1,
        R.id.exec3Set2,
        R.id.exec3Set3,
        R.id.btnSave
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_board_view);

    buttons = new ArrayList<Button>(BUTTON_IDS.length);
    int position = 0;
    for (int id: BUTTON_IDS) {
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(id);
        button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button.setTag(position++);
        buttons.add(button);
    }
}
```

Обработчик события click:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        JSONObject ex1 = new JSONObject();

        try {
            int i = (int) v.getTag();
            while( i < 3 ){ 
                ex1.put( "set" + i,((Button) v).getText().toString() );                    
                i++;
            }
        }

        switch ((int) v.getTag()) {
            case 0:
                // действия
                break;
            case 1:
                // действия
                break;
            // ...
        }
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: почему вы считаете, что в Tag View есть какое-то число и что данный цикл будет перебирать ваши кнопки?

Comment: @pavlofff при создании коллекции кнопок в цикле из приведенного в ссылке образца у элементов button устанавливаются теги через метод setTag()

Comment: @pavlofff обновил вопрос